# How to consume own api with Laravel Passport and client credentials?

Tags: vuejs2, axios, laravel-passport, laravel-5.5

I have correctly set it up for users with personal access tokens, but would like to protect ALL api routes. Reading the documentation it sounds like [Client Credentials Grant Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens) is what I need. I have a Client ID and Client Secret in my `.env` file; I have added the `client` middleware using `\Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckClientCredentials::class` and have applied this to some api routes.

I am using Vue and axios.

How do I go about getting and setting the token I need to access these protected api routes?

Answer (score 3):

The Laravel docs are realy not clear about "Consuming your own API". I also Googled for days and even subscribed to Laracasts. Not helpfull. I got it working now, this is a dump from my notes.

Step 1 - install Passport

```
composer require laravel/passport
php artisan migrate
php artisan passport:install
```

Step 2 - edit /app/User.php

```
use HasApiTokens,Notifiable
```

Step 3 - edit /app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php

```
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
}
```

Step 4 - edit /config/auth.php

```
enter code     'api' => [
    'driver' => 'passport',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
```

Step 5 - Frontend Quickstart

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

Step 6 - edit /resources/assets/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Step 7 - authentication routes and views scaffold

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Step 8 - edit /app/Http/Kernel.php

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
            \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
```

Step 9 - edit /routes/web.php (this answers your question)

```
// Authorization routes Laravel Passport
Auth::routes();

// Landing page
Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome');});

// Auth protected routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    Route::get('example', function(){ return view('example'); });
}
//(stolen from /vendor/laravel/passport/src/RouteRegistrar.php - forAuthorization method)
```

Step 10 - compile assets

```
npm i -g npm
npm install
npm run dev
```

Step 11 - nothing. You don't have to do anything on the VueJS and Axios side.

You can just do:

```
axios.get('URL_XYZ')
.then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

Laravel docs:

> When using this method of authentication, the default Laravel JavaScript scaffolding instructs Axios to always send the X-CSRF-TOKEN and X-Requested-With headers.

Sources:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport
https://www.itechempires.com/2017/09/laravel-5-5-api-user-authentication-passport-package/

Comment: One note: in the Kernel, make sure CreateFreshApiToken is BELOW             \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class, this tripped me up at one point.